# CSS border-radius set on hover and hover-out with transition 1s

Tags: html, css

I have a button. On hover a increase it's width and change border radius with transition of 1s. But on hover out border-radius set with initial value(in this case 50%) immediately. 
I want to wait 1s and then set border-radius 50% when hovering out.

```css
.profile-avatar-change {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(#fd1999, #a60fe7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.profile-avatar-change:hover {
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.profile-avatar-change:hover .hover-text {
  opacity: 1;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50rem;
}

.profile-avatar-change .hover-text {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: none;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a src="https://codepen.io/robin3317/pen/zYYwxEB/license">MIT License</a> <br><br>

<a class="profile-avatar-change" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  <span class="hover-text">Edit Profile Picture</span>
</a>
```

[Here is codepen demo](https://codepen.io/robin3317/pen/zYYwxEB?editors=1100) (I am using SCSS as CSS pre)

Comment: Do u want the hover out clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a transition with a delay of 1s that operates when the item is not hovered:

```
.profile-avatar-change:not(:hover) {
  transition: border-radius 1s 1s;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.profile-avatar-change {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(#fd1999, #a60fe7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.profile-avatar-change:hover {
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.profile-avatar-change:not(:hover) {
  transition: border-radius 1s 1s;
}

.profile-avatar-change:hover .hover-text {
  opacity: 1;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50rem;
}

.profile-avatar-change .hover-text {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: none;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a src="https://codepen.io/robin3317/pen/zYYwxEB/license">MIT License</a> <br><br>

<a class="profile-avatar-change" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  <span class="hover-text">Edit Profile Picture</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work fine.. plz try this code..

**css**

```
.profile-avatar-change {
  transition: all 1.1s;
}
.profile-avatar-change:hover {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```